# How to record desktop screen video using recordRTC node module of selected screen area?

Tags: node.js, video-capture, nwjs

I am working on desktop application using NW.js wherein required to record selected area of desktop screen. currently using RecordRTC node module for recording video. but this gives me full screen video recording. please assist if there any other package to achieve this across platforms (win/linux/mac).

Answer (score 1):

Please check this demo (name as "**Record Cropped Screen using RecordRTC**"):

- https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/simple-demos/record-cropped-screen.html

Here is complete HTML code (try on any HTTPs page or localhost or node-webkit):

```
<button id="btn-start-recording">Start Recording</button>
<button id="btn-stop-recording" style="display: none;">Stop Recording</button>

<br><hr>

<div id="edit-panel" style="border-bottom: 1px solid;">
    <div>
        <label for="x">X</label>
        <input type="number" name="x" id="x" value="0" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="y">Y</label>
        <input type="number" name="y" id="y" value="0" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="w">Width (-1 = Full size)</label>
        <input type="number" name="w" id="w" value="-1" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="h">Height (-1 = Full size)</label>
        <input type="number" name="h" id="h" value="-1" />
    </div>

    <button id="update" style="display: none;">Update X-Y Width-Height Coordinates</button>

    <canvas></canvas>
</div>

<video id="mediaElement"></video>

<script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.WebRTC-Experiment.com/getScreenId.js"></script>
<script>
// this script tag is taken from: https://github.com/andersevenrud/webrtc-screenshare-crop-demo
var CROP_X = 10;
var CROP_Y = 20;
var CROP_W = 320; // default width
var CROP_H = 240; // default height
var VIDEO_WIDTH = 0;
var VIDEO_HEIGHT = 0;
var MAX_VIDEO_WIDTH = 1920;
var MAX_VIDEO_HEIGHT = 1080;
var _canvas;
var _context;

var htmlCanvasElement = document.querySelector('canvas');

// Form elements
document.getElementById("x").value = CROP_X;
document.getElementById("y").value = CROP_Y;
document.getElementById("w").value = CROP_W;
document.getElementById("h").value = CROP_H;

document.getElementById("update").onclick = function() {
    var x = document.getElementById("x").value << 0;
    var y = document.getElementById("y").value << 0;
    var w = document.getElementById("w").value << 0;
    var h = document.getElementById("h").value << 0;

    if (x >= 0) {
        CROP_X = x;
    }
    if (y >= 0) {
        CROP_Y = y;
    }

    CROP_W = w || 0;
    CROP_H = h || 0;
};

_context = htmlCanvasElement.getContext('2d');

/**
 * Crops a video frame and shows it to the user
 */
function CropFrame(ev, stream, video, callback) {
    callback = callback || function() {};

    _canvas = htmlCanvasElement;

    if (CROP_X < 0) {
        CROP_X = 0;
    }
    if (CROP_Y < 0) {
        CROP_Y = 0;
    }
    if (CROP_W <= 0) {
        CROP_W = VIDEO_WIDTH;
    }
    if (CROP_H <= 0) {
        CROP_H = VIDEO_HEIGHT;
    }
    if (CROP_W > MAX_VIDEO_WIDTH) {
        CROP_W = MAX_VIDEO_WIDTH;
    }
    if (CROP_H > MAX_VIDEO_HEIGHT) {
        CROP_W = MAX_VIDEO_HEIGHT;
    }

    _canvas.width = CROP_W;
    _canvas.height = CROP_H;

    _context.drawImage(video, CROP_X, CROP_Y, CROP_W, CROP_H, 0, 0, CROP_W, CROP_H);

    // We need to scale down the image or else we get HTTP 414 Errors
    // Also we scale down because of RTC message length restriction
    var scanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    scanvas.width = _canvas.width;
    scanvas.height = _canvas.height;

    var wRatio = _canvas.width / 320;
    var hRatio = _canvas.height / 240;
    var maxRatio = Math.max(wRatio, hRatio);
    if (maxRatio > 1) {
        scanvas.width = _canvas.width / maxRatio;
        scanvas.height = _canvas.height / maxRatio;
    }
    scanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(_canvas, 0, 0, scanvas.width, scanvas.height);

    callback(scanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"));
}

var recorder;

function captureScreen(cb) {
    getScreenId(function(error, sourceId, screen_constraints) {
        navigator.getUserMedia(screen_constraints, cb, function(error) {
            console.error('getScreenId error', error);

            alert('Failed to capture your screen. Please check Chrome console logs for further information.');
        });
    });
}

var mediaElement = document.querySelector('#mediaElement');

document.querySelector('#btn-start-recording').onclick = function() {
    document.querySelector('#btn-start-recording').style.display = 'none';

    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
    captureScreen(function(screen) {
        var inited = false;

        mediaElement.ontimeupdate = function(ev) {
            if (!inited) {
                VIDEO_WIDTH = mediaElement.offsetWidth;
                VIDEO_HEIGHT = mediaElement.offsetHeight;

                mediaElement.style.display = 'none';
                document.querySelector('#edit-panel').style.display = 'block';

                inited = true;
            }

            CropFrame(ev, screen, mediaElement);
        };

        mediaElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(screen);
        mediaElement.play();
        mediaElement.screen = screen;

        addStreamStopListener(screen, function() {
            document.querySelector('#btn-stop-recording').onclick();
        });

        // RecordRTC goes here
        var captureStream = htmlCanvasElement.captureStream();
        recorder = RecordRTC(captureStream, {
            type: 'video'
        });
        recorder.startRecording();

        document.querySelector('#btn-stop-recording').style.display = 'inline';
    });
};

document.querySelector('#btn-stop-recording').onclick = function() {
    document.querySelector('#btn-stop-recording').style.display = 'none';

    recorder.stopRecording(function() {
        var blob = recorder.getBlob();

        document.querySelector('#edit-panel').style.display = 'none';
        mediaElement.style.display = 'block';

        mediaElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        mediaElement.play();

        if (mediaElement.screen && mediaElement.screen.getVideoTracks) {
            mediaElement.screen.stop();
            mediaElement.screen = null;
        }

        document.querySelector('#btn-start-recording').style.display = 'inline';
    });
};

function addStreamStopListener(stream, callback) {
    var streamEndedEvent = 'ended';
    if ('oninactive' in stream) {
        streamEndedEvent = 'inactive';
    }
    stream.addEventListener(streamEndedEvent, function() {
        callback();
        callback = function() {};
    }, false);
    stream.getAudioTracks().forEach(function(track) {
        track.addEventListener(streamEndedEvent, function() {
            callback();
            callback = function() {};
        }, false);
    });
    stream.getVideoTracks().forEach(function(track) {
        track.addEventListener(streamEndedEvent, function() {
            callback();
            callback = function() {};
        }, false);
    });
}

function querySelectorAll(selector) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
}

querySelectorAll('input').forEach(function(input) {
    input.onkeyup = input.oninput = function() {
        if (!document.querySelector('#update').onclick) return;
        document.querySelector('#update').onclick();
    };
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I am trying to execute it in NW.JS App it gives me following error in console :      

getScreenId error 
NavigatorUserMediaError
constraintName
:
""
message
:
""
name
:
"InvalidStateError"
__proto__
:
NavigatorUserMediaError

is this error related to webkit version or getScreenId file load error?

Comment: please make this package to work with typescript like code intellisense

Comment: Thanks for this package, I love that. Please make its documentation more clear and do create some tutorials which you target low or medium level developers. I find much difficulty to work with this package due to not availability of proper tutorials and code intellisense.